# Promise.all with promise chain inside

Tags: javascript, node.js, asynchronous, promise, es6-promise

I have a method like this:

```
doSomeRequests(listOfRequestParameters) {
  let requests = listOfRequestParameters.map(parmeter => {
    return axios.get(url + parmeter)
    .then(data => {
      const parameters= data.parameters;
      return axios.delete(url, parameters)
    })
  })
  return Promise.all(requests);
}
```

In this function I want to complete API requests for each element in a list (listOfRequestParameters), but for every element in the list I have to do two API requests.

The axios methods both return Promises.

The problem is that I do catch the result of the Promise returned y doSomeRequests method, but if one API requests fail I get an UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning.

What am I missing? Is there a way to do this kind of Promise chain?

Comment: So you are saying you do `doSomeRequests(..).then().catch()` and get that warning? Nothing seems wrong with your chain approach

Comment: No, I don't. See my answer for details, thank you for your help.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to @charlietfl for asking me if I really do `doSomeRequests(..).then().catch()`. Turns out I don't, I accidentally did `doSomeRequests(..).then().then()` but was somehow convinced the I need to search for the error in the "complex" Promise chain.

Anyway, I am sorry for the useless question, thank you for your help.

Comment: Wasn't useless. You confirmed that your approach was correct in concept anyway

Answer (score 0):

You need to make sure the map call returns a list of promises, simplifying with async/await you'll get something along the lines:

```js
async doSomeRequests(listOfRequestParameters) {
  return Promise.all(listOfRequestParameters.map(async parmeter => {
    const data = await axios.get(url + parameter);
    const parameters = data.parameters;

    return axios.delete(url, parameters);
  }));
}

await doSomeRequests(listOfRequestParameters);
```